# ASP.NET MVC - On Input Value Change Update URL Parmaeters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have a mapping application that I would like to place the extent values in the URL. (XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX). I currently have a javascript file that handles all the mapping related functionality. This script also creates, and updates hidden inputs with the appropriate values when he extent is changed. I would like to have a JQUERY event listener to then handle the appropriate url manipulation from inside the view.

I am using dojo to create the hidden inputs. This is working and updates values appropriately.

```
    domConstruct.place("<input type='hidden' id='xmin-h'/>", "av-map-div");
    domConstruct.place("<input type='hidden' id='ymin-h'/>", "av-map-div");
    domConstruct.place("<input type='hidden' id='xmax-h'/>", "av-map-div");
    domConstruct.place("<input type='hidden' id='ymax-h'/>", "av-map-div");
    domConstruct.place("<input type='hidden' id='wkid-h'/>", "av-map-div");
```

And then on extent change...

```
    map.on("extent-change", function () {
        var jextent = getExtentParm();
        console.log(jextent);
    });
```

which calls...

```
var getExtentParm = function getExtentParm() {
    console.log("get extent");

    var XMIN;
    var YMIN;
    var XMAX;
    var YMAX;
    var WKID;

    XMIN = map.extent.xmin;
    YMIN = map.extent.ymin;
    XMAX = map.extent.xmax;
    YMAX = map.extent.ymax;
    WKID = map.extent.spatialReference.latestWkid;

    var hXmin = document.getElementById("xmin-h");
    domAttr.set(hXmin, "value", XMIN);

    var hYmin = document.getElementById("ymin-h");
    domAttr.set(hYmin, "value", YMIN);

    var hXmax = document.getElementById("xmax-h");
    domAttr.set(hXmax, "value", XMAX);

    var hYmax = document.getElementById("ymax-h");
    domAttr.set(hYmax, "value", YMAX);

    var hWkid = document.getElementById("wkid-h");
    domAttr.set(hWkis, "value", WKID);


}
```

Inside my view I would then like to manipulate the URL Query String. Bellow is my most recent attempt. It fails.

```
@section scripts {
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/av-map.js"></script>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        var parsedUrl = $.url(currentUrl);
        var params = parsedUrl.param();

        $("#av-map-div").on("change","xmin-h", function () {
            params["XMIN"] = $("xmin-h").val();
            setURL();
        });

        $("#av-map-div").on("change", "ymin-h", function () {
            params["YMIN"] = $("ymin-h").val();
            setURL();
        });

        $("#av-map-div").on("change", "xmax-h", function () {
            params["XMAX"] = $("xmax-h").val();
            setURL();
        });

        $("#av-map-div").on("change", "ymax-h", function () {
            params["YMAX"] = $("ymax-h").val();
            setURL();
        });


        function setURL() {
            var newURL = "?" + $.param(params);
            console.log(newURL);
        };

    });

</script>
```

How would the best way to do this be? Bonus points, what would the mvc way of doing this be?

**EDIT / CLARIFICATION**

The values of the `<inputs>` are being updated by a map.js file. It is using ESRI's api and thus I am handling it separately from the rest of the application. This script both creates the hidden inputs (have experimented with a paragraph) as well as updates these values every time the map is scrolled, panned, or zoomed. My hope is to get these parameters to pass into the URL so that when other functions that us the query string are in use (thus re loading the page) the maps extent can be maintained. The map.js has a function that can grab XMIN, XMAXm YMIN, YMAX from the url and adjust the map appropriately. Otherwise it resets to its initial extent.

It sets the extents form the URL using the bellow JS..

```
var setExtent = function setExtent() {
        console.log("set map extent");
        var xmin = getUrlParameter('XMIN');
        var ymin = getUrlParameter('YMIN');
        var xmax = getUrlParameter('XMAX');
        var ymax = getUrlParameter('YMAX');
        var sr = getUrlParameter('WKID');

        if (typeof xmin == 'undefined' || typeof ymin == 'undefined' || typeof xmax == 'undefined' || typeof ymax == 'undefined' || typeof sr == 'undefined') {
            console.log('null or invalid extent');
        }

        else {
            var ext = new Extent(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, new SpatialReference({ wkid: sr }));
            map.setExtent(ext);
        }
    }

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        console.log('get url param');
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)), sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'), sParameterName, i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                console.log(sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1]);
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };
```

My controller looks like:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, double? XMIN, double? YMIN, double? XMAX, double? YMAX, int? WKID)
    {
        ViewBag.XMIN = XMIN;
        ViewBag.YMIN = YMIN;
        ViewBag.XMAX = XMAX;
        ViewBag.YMAX = YMAX;
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.AGMT_NUM_PARM = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "AGMT_NUM_DESC" : "";
        ViewBag.EXP_DATE_SORT_PARM = sortOrder == "EXP_DATE" ? "EXP_DATE_DESC" : "EXP_DATE";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


        var agreements = from a in db.LANDDATA_MORNINGSTAR_AGREEMENTS select a;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            agreements = agreements.Where(a => a.AGMT_NUM.Contains(searchString)
                                   || a.AGMT_NAME.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "AGMT_NUM_DESC":
                agreements = agreements.OrderByDescending(a => a.AGMT_NUM);
                break;
            case "EXP_DATE":
                agreements = agreements.OrderBy(a => a.EXPR_DATE);
                break;
            case "EXP_DATE_DESC":
                agreements = agreements.OrderByDescending(a => a.EXPR_DATE);
                break;
            default:
                agreements = agreements.OrderBy(a => a.AGMT_NUM);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(agreements.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

Comment: where does it fail? and you are listening to `$("#av-map-div")` changes , does it really fire a change event ?

Comment: The javascript file sets a listener that posts changes to the hidden inputs that reside in #av-map-div.

Comment: one issue might be the order scripts are loaded in.. investigating further..

Comment: _hidden inputs that reside in #av-map-div_, doesn't matter. Unfortunately `change` does not help if you are trying to listen to changes to the hidden inputs xmin, xmax etc.. inside another div, and then update the query parameters accordingly.I encourage you to check how `change` works from jQuery docs.. I will share a proposed option..

Comment: _parameters to pass into the URL_,  the moment url changes like `location.href = http://abcd.com?xmin=1&ymin=2&.....` from the `setUrl()`, your location will be updated and the browser will navigate. And if you update the URL every time the map extent changes, this will navigate & update, might result in an endless loop. I hope you are following.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `input` for each of your properties like:

```
<div id="myProps">
    <input type="number" data-propname="xmin-h" value="yourvalue" class="propclass" />
    <input type="number" data-propname="xmax-h" value="yourvalue" class="propclass" />
    <!-- all the rest here -->
</div>
```

You can then listen to the change on this inputs using `blur` (when lost focus on input, change the url):

```
var config = {
    mypropscontainer: '#myProps',
    myprop: '.propclass'
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(config.mypropscontainer).on('blur', config.myprop, function () {
        // This will find all the properties and put them in a list
        var allProps = $(config.mypropscontainer).find(myprop);

        // Iterate the list and create the new url
        var _url = '/controller/action?';
        $.each(allProps, function (index, item) {
            var _propname = $(item).data('propname'); // Will return xmin-h, xmax-h, etc...
            var _propvalue = $(item).val();

            _url = _url + _propname + "=" + _propvalue;

            // If is not the last element append also an '&'
            if (index !== allProps.Count - 1) {
                _url = _url + '&';
            }
        });

        // Do something with your _url here
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case, are the inputs visible to the user. I was hoping to handle this behind the scenes.

Comment: Then how are the updates occur? Or why you need the actual change event to modify the url?

Comment: the values are being updated by a map.js file. It is using ESRI's api and thus must be handled separately from the rest of the application. I have this script creating the hidden inputs (have experimented with a paragraph) as well as updates these values every time the map is scrolled. My hope is to get these parameters to pass into the URL so that when other functions that us the query string thus re loading the page the maps extent can be maintained. The map.js has a function that can grab XMIN, XMAXm YMIN, YMAX from the url and adjust the map appropriately.